# asp.net For Each in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model.

```
public class OtchetDetails
{
    String bob_name;
    String brigade_name;
    Int64 timeToTask;
    String status;
}
```

I pass value in view:

```
  List<OtchetDetails> taskOtchet = taskOtchetRepository.getOtchet(id);
  return View(taskOtchet);
```

How do I display the content in a cycle?

```
   <% @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td class="left">  @item.bob_name</td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
  }
```

bob_name not found. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code in your view. I hope that helps you.

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<OtchetDetails>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td class="left">  @item.bob_name</td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove <% , and it will be ok

Comment: Why would you remove the @ before item?